# Live Streaming Video in Opencv-Python with WebCam

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on Python's Django language. I'm implementing the "Live Video Streaming" with webcam in opencv-python. But "Live Video Streaming" functionality is successfully on my local server.

Whenever any user access the website through my IP address, that time `WebCam` is unable to capture our video and getting below error  message.

```
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't find camera device
```

How can I debug this type of error?

Comment: First, are you serving over http, or https? Because most browsers don't support user media over http from hosts over localhost. Second, if you're using webcams, have you tried opening the Javascript console for `getUserMedia` errors?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.